# React + Redux: undefined initial state and reducer not called as expected

Tags: reactjs, redux

I think this is pretty primitive. I'm having trouble with two things:

1.`this.props.appState` is `undefined` in the constructor. This is unexpected because in the reducer I have the initial state set to `{ appState: { name: "World!" } }` and I was expecting this lead to initialization of the `appState`. So I added the if statement which I know is just a temporary fix before I find the actual issue.

2.When I click on the button and call the `sendAction` handler, the execution flow never reaches the reducer function!

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    if (this.props.appState) {
      this.state = { name: this.props.appState.name };
    }
    else {
      this.state = { name: "Unknown" };
    }
    this.nameChanged = this.nameChanged.bind(this);
    this.sendAction = this.sendAction.bind(this);
  }

  nameChanged(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  sendAction(event) {
    this.props.saveName(this.state.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>
        <h1>Hello, {this.state.name}!</h1>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.nameChanged} />
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" onClick={this.sendAction} />
      </pre>
    );
  }
}

const appReducer = (state = { appState: { name: "World!" } }, action) => {
  debugger;
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SAVE_NAME":
      return Object.assign({}, state, { name: action.name });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const AppContainer = ReactRedux.connect(
  state => ({ appState: state.appState }),
  dispatch => ({
    saveName: (name) => Redux.bindActionCreators({ type: "SAVE_NAME", name }, dispatch)
  })
)(App);

const combinedReducers = Redux.combineReducers({
  appReducer
});

const store = Redux.createStore(combinedReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer />
  </ReactRedux.Provider>,
  document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]
);
```

Comment: in a `constructor` function, try to call `props` without 'this' (for example `props.appState` instead of `this.props.appState`)

Comment: @CarmeloCatalfamo nope thats not it at all. Anyway you need to access the props from `this`, how else you would access it ?

Comment: @WilomGfx you have props as argument of constructor function, you don't need 'this' in there

Comment: @CarmeloCatalfamo either way, you should access it with `this`, no need to mix and match how you access things inside an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your reducer is called : `appReducer`, you will need to access the `appState` property on `appReducer.appState` in `mapStateToProps` like so

```
const AppContainer = ReactRedux.connect(
  state => ({ appState: state.appReducer.appState }),
  dispatch => ({
    saveName: (name) => Redux.bindActionCreators({ type: "SAVE_NAME", name }, dispatch)
  })
)(App);
```

For you second problem you can either do

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    saveName: (name) => {
      dispatch({ type: "SAVE_NAME", name })
    }
  }
}
```

Or have this defined like so.

```
const actionCreators = {
    saveName: (name) => {
       return { type: "SAVE_NAME", name }
     },
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
}
```

And then in connect

```
const AppContainer = ReactRedux.connect(
              state => ({ appState: state.appReducer.appState }),
              mapDispatchToProps,
              })
            )(App);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem with undefined initialization. But what about the other problem? The one with reducer never called?

Comment: @Mehran You're using `bindActionCreators` incorrectly. That is why your reducer is never being called. `bindActionCreators` takes "An action creator, or an object whose values are action creators.", and the `dispatch` function as arguments. It returns an object that has your action creators wrapped in dispatch and mapped to keys of the method names provided within the first argument of `bindActionCreators`. Your `saveName` method is returning an object, not dispatching an action.

Comment: What @KyleRichardson said. I'll update my answer with the fix.

Comment: I'll up vote your answer but I want my 50% cut! :) kidding of course.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, both.

Comment: @mehran, I'd suggest you look at Dan's (creator of redux) free courses on redux on egghead.io , really awesome :)!